# How to set C compiler in defsystem?

Tags: common-lisp, cc, cffi

I'm trying to loads `cl-mpi` system with `quicklisp`. This is the system definition:

```
(asdf:defsystem cl-mpi
    :description "Common Lisp bindings for the Message Passing Interface (MPI)"
    :author "Alex Fukunaga"
    :version "0.1.0"
    :license "MIT"
    :depends-on (:cffi :cffi-grovel)
    :components
    ((:file "packages")
     (:file "cl-mpi-configure" :depends-on ("packages"))
     (cffi-grovel:grovel-file "mpi-grovel" :depends-on ("packages" "cl-mpi-configure"))
     (:file "mpi" :depends-on ("packages"))))
```

This fails to compile because it "doesn't know" what `$CC` is set to. I need it to be set to `mpicc`. I found the code, where I think it sets it:

```
(defun cc-compile-and-link (input-file output-file &key library)
  (let ((arglist
         `(,(or (getenv "CC") *cc*)
           ,@*cpu-word-size-flags*
           ,@*cc-flags*
           ;; add the cffi directory to the include path to make common.h visible
           ,(format nil "-I~A"
                    (directory-namestring
                     (truename
                      (asdf:system-definition-pathname :cffi-grovel))))
           ,@(when library *platform-library-flags*)
           "-o" ,(native-namestring output-file)
           ,(native-namestring input-file))))
    (when library
      ;; if it's a library that may be used, remove it
      ;; so we won't possibly be overwriting the code of any existing process
      (ignore-some-conditions (file-error)
        (delete-file output-file)))
    (apply #'invoke arglist)))
```

The above is inside the `asdf` package. However I can't understand how to change the `defsystem` to account for the compiler.

PS: This is what the error looks like:

```
External process exited with code 1.
Command was: "cc" "-m64" "-I/home/wvxvw/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.11.1/" 
"-o" "/home/wvxvw/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.1.2-1.fc18-linux-x64/home/wvxvw/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-mpi/mpi-grovel" 
"/home/wvxvw/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.1.2-1.fc18-linux-x64/home/wvxvw/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-mpi/mpi-grovel.c"

Output was:
/home/wvxvw/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.1.2-1.fc18-linux-x64/home/wvxvw/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-mpi/mpi-grovel.c:6:34: 
fatal error: /usr/include/mpi/mpi.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.
```

formatted for readability. The compiler doesn't find the header because it's not the proper compiler (`mpicc` "knows" where to look for `mpi.h` header, it won't be looking in the `/usr/include`).

---

Sorry for the confusion. I could set `$CC` to `mpicc`, but it still doesn't find `/usr/include/mpich-x86_64/mpi.h` header - so maybe I need to set include path rather than compiler? If so, how?

This is how I managed to set it to `mpicc`:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cffi-grovel)
  (setf cffi-grovel::*cc* "mpicc"))
```

before `defsystem`

EDIT: Whoops, it's `cffi` that generates the bad include :( which looks like this:

```
#include </usr/include/mpi/mpi.h>
```

instead of:

```
#include "mpi.h"
```

Is there any way to do something about it?

---

Applying lots of hackery and trickery I could get it working. It appears that the path to the library was set in the code itself, so I had to

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :cffi-grovel)
  (setf cffi-grovel::*cc* "mpicc"
        mpi::*mpi-header-file* "/usr/include/mpich-x86_64/mpi.h"))
```

I also had to make several changes particular to my system to compile the whole thing.

But, I would like this question to be answered in general, if possible! I.e., what is the way to set the C compiler and its options in a generic and acceptable way?

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1):

cl-mpi contains a file called "cl-mpi-configure.lisp". This file looks like it is intended to be changed to configure cl-mpi to use the correct paths for your systems.

Specifically this line:

```
(defvar *mpi-header-file* "/usr/include/mpi/mpi.h") ; this is where  ubuntu apt-get install puts mpi.h.
```

defines the path for the mpi header file. You will need to change this line to use the path of mpi.h on your system. This is a little annoying since you can't will need to use a local version, rather than downloading directly from quicklisp.

Alternatively you could make a patch to determine the path more intelligently (for example using `pkg-config`), and submit it upstream.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a general mechanism in quicklisp or other relevant bits to installing a package, perhaps in asdf land, that would allow overriding where such things would be looked for as some path prefix?  That seems better than patching packages one by one.

Comment: CFFI provides that using pkg-config. But the mpi package doesn't use that functionality.